# HTTP header prefixing and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Rails4 does uppercase and prefix "HTTP_" http header names that are not in the standard list of of header names:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/headers.rb#L124

So 'access_token' becomes 'HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN'. And in order to access 'access_token' I have to use request.headers('HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN').

My problem is that this isn't working with rspec:

```
get path,nil,{access_token:"the token"}
```

The header name remains untouched. So I need to use:

```
get path,nil,{HTTP_ACCESS_TOKEN:"the token"}
```

How can I make rspec requests use the same header name as a XHR javascript would do?

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/path", true);
request.setRequestHeader("access-token","my token");
```

Is there a patch for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only in production environments it seems to add the HTTP_ prefix